# TextInputLayout causes design problems

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle

Every time I **replace** **EditText** with **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout**, all the **information in the field** (in my case, the password input field) **simply disappears**, in the sense that in any case a hint is needed there, but there is literally none , he just disappears. I want to use this particular tool because I want to add the ability to view the entered password in the field, since I myself often encounter the problem of having to check the correctness of its spelling several times.

[With TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9bTu.png)
[Without TextInput, just EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYW6.png)

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bglast"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonlogin"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_button"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.338"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgotpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/forgotfull"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyHint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonlogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.937" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:text="@string/Still"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyHint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.424"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonlogin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.208" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:text="@string/get"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.645"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonlogin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.208" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intersemibold"
        android:text="Welcome here,"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/passwordico"
        android:drawablePadding="16px"
        android:hint="Type your password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyHint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/GreyHint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type your e-mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/GreyHint"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyHint"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/GreyHint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/GreyHint"
        android:textColorLink="@color/GreyHint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.43"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Password"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.044"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.037"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intersemibold"
        android:text="Good luck with your search!"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.225" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Tried to add implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
in the Gradle App File, but it did not lead to anything, it caused errors, for what reasons I don’t know. I tried to simply insert a viewing eye into a regular EditText - without result. Therefore, I want to continue to try to use it, but first I need to fix it -_-